# How could I use Material You web in an HTML/Express project?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, material-design, styling

I would like to make a web application, and I would like to use Material You web for it, but I don't want to have to use JavaScript or Node for it. I will use Node if I have to.

Is there any way for me to use Material 3 web without JavaScript or Node? If not, how would I use it in say an Express app?

Is there maybe a CDN link I could use? I've looked around and I can't find one but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

I tried installing it via NPM, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work using Express, which is what I am using for my project.

Comment: [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/browse/@material/web@1.0.1/) (and several other sites) provide CDN services for all NPM packages, `@material/web` included

Comment: @smallpepperz How would I go about using that in an HTML file? I tried adding `all.js` into my document, but it did not seem to work.